# How is it that some software knows the correct orientation of an image and other software does not?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop, photos, rotate, windows-photo-viewer

I download some photos off Google drive and when I open them in Windows Photo Viewer some are incorrectly oriented. I opened them in Photoshop with the intent to rotate them but Photoshop already displays them with the correct orientation. I want to upload the photos to websites, such as Facebook so what is the easiest way to rotate them and how do I make sure they will be correct on Facebook? Is what's going on is that Photoshop is smart enough to autodetect things such as faces and rotate the photos automatically?

Comment: This question would probably be more on-topic on Software Recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I considered that, but part of the question is why does it happen?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I disagree. He's not asking for software, and he doesn't have the question structured as Software Recommendations should be. As well, we do not migrate to beta sites.

Comment: Windows Photo Viewer has buttons on it that rotate the picture and 'save' the orientation. There is no need to download another program or load Photoshop to do this. (Although, if you have lots of photos, @preyingrazor's answer seems to be the best bet.)

Comment: As you've noticed, Windows Photo Viewer isn't very good so you might want to check out Picasa (by Google) instead. Although it's a full library management tool, it also comes with a nice fast photo viewer which does actually look at the EXIF data correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Most digital cameras record orientation in EXIF data of the image file. Some image processors such as Photoshop, automatically read this data and auto-correct the orientation.

I checked Google and this is the easiest solution I found that works for me. It adds a context menu option to rotate all pictures in a folder to the right orientation.

Click [here](http://www.pilpi.net/software/JPEG-EXIF_autorotate.php) to go to the download page.

Best part is it's free and only weighs in at 256K. It works on Windows 8 as well.